# PHPDoc - how to mark constructor function in PHP

Tags: php, constructor, annotations, markup, phpdoc

In JSDoc i can mark my constructor function with `@constructor`.
Now i tried to find in the PHPDoc specs how to do the same for a PHP constructor but they never mention anything similar. What is the proper way to mark my constructor in PHP.

This:

```
/**
 * @constructor
 */
public function __construct()
{

}
```

Seems to be invalid.

Comment: why do you need to mark the constructor?!

Comment: Hmm, maybe just trying to be too tidy here? Are there no legitimate reasons (which I cannot think of right now) to do so?

Comment: Constructor is not called as a normal method, once you do `$obj = new Class`, you call it, so you may want to put comments for the class instead for the constructor? For constructor you may only specify the params, if there are. If none - just don't comment. And no return type

Comment: I agree, the constructor is mostly self-documenting in what it does (ie. it makes the instance) so it's superfluous to have to re-iterate that. I'd normally document any side-effects or additional processing beyond defaulting properties and state. I do find it annoying that the Class-level doc-blocks don't show up in most IDE's code-assist when typing `new Class()`, which makes you feel like writing the class docs on the constructor (wrongly!).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP documentation generators will recognize the `__construct()` method as the constructor.  No special tag is required.

Comment: It is needed some constructor tag, becuase there could be static constructor methods in order to encapsulate different create intentions for the same class.

Comment: @jhvaras, do mean non-constructor methods that would act as factories, each one calling the actual true constructor?  PHP is not natively capable of multiple constructors, thus only via a factory pattern could you mimic multiple creation paths.  In that scenario, I would perhaps add `@see __construct()` in the docblocks of those non-constructor methods, if I was trying to highlight their acting as a factory.  Presumably you'd also make the true constructor private/protected, so that only the factory can return objects to the caller?

Comment: That is exactly the point. If you need several constructors on diferent approaches/contexts you can private the `__construct()` method and add public static factory methods, usually with different arguments. This decouples contexts and hides the creational complexity. So a special tag would be usefull.